# How can I use extern image link in Fiftyone?

Tags: dataset, fiftyone

Is this possible to use an extern images link (in google image for example) in fiftyone instead of downloading images and loading them?

If it's not the case, did you know if an alternative exists?

Answer (score 2):

Great question. This functionality is available in [FiftyOne Teams](https://voxel51.com/fiftyone-teams/), with which you can point samples directly to an `https://` image (as well as S3, GCS, Azure, MinIO media). If you're using the open source library, then you should download the images first.